# How to archive the AuditData table on a contentDB?

Tags: powershell, sql-server, auditing

I have a content db whose audit log is getting really big (60GB) and it's starting to effect the DB. I know I can go in and delete entries via Powershell, but I wanted to archive this table before I actually removed the data. Is there a way to do this in Powershell or is it best from the SQL Server? If so how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the SQL data using SQL management tools and Trim data using PowerShell.

Another option is using PowerShell to archive and Trim as explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx#proc2)

I found below script from [here](http://shokochino-sharepointexperience.blogspot.com/2013/05/create-auditing-reports-in-sharepoint.html)

**Below script will export audit data into a CSV file**

```
$tabName = "AuditLog"

#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$tabName”

#Define Columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn SiteUrl,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn SiteID,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ItemName,([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ItemType,([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn UserID,([string])
$col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn UserName,([string])
$col7 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Occurred,([DateTime])
$col8 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Event,([string])
$col9 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Description,([string])
$col10 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn EventSource,([string])
$col11 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn SourceName,([string])
$col12 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn EventData,([string])
$col13 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn MachineName,([string])
$col14 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn MachineIP,([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)
$table.columns.add($col6)
$table.columns.add($col7)
$table.columns.add($col8)
$table.columns.add($col9)
$table.columns.add($col10)
$table.columns.add($col11)
$table.columns.add($col12)
$table.columns.add($col13)
$table.columns.add($col14)

$site = Get-SPSite -Identity http://SiteCollectionName
$wssQuery = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($site)
$auditCol = $site.Audit.GetEntries($wssQuery)
$root = $site.RootWeb

for ($i=0; $i -le ($auditCol.Count)-1 ; $i++)
{
    #Get the Entry Item from the Collection
    $entry = $auditCol.item($i)

    #Create a row
    $row = $table.NewRow()

    #find the Current UserName 
    foreach($User in $root.SiteUsers)
    {
        if($entry.UserId -eq $User.Id)
        {
             $UserName = $User.UserLogin
        }
    }   

    #find the Item Name
    foreach($List in $root.Lists)
    {
        if($entry.ItemId -eq $List.Id)
        {
             $ItemName = $List.Title
        }
    }   

    #Define Description for the Event Property
     switch ($entry.Event)
    {
        AuditMaskChange{$eventName = "The audit flags are changed for the audited object."}
        ChildDelete {$eventName = "A child of the audited object is deleted."}
        ChildMove {$eventName = "A child of the audited object is moved."}
        CheckIn {$eventName = " A document is checked in."}
        'Copy' {$eventName = "The audited item is copied."}
        Delete {$eventName = "The audited object is deleted."}
        EventsDeleted {$eventName = "Some audit entries are deleted from SharePoint database."}
        'Move' {$eventName = "The audited object is moved."}
        Search {$eventName = "The audited object is searched."}
        SecGroupCreate {$eventName = "A group is created for the site collection. (This action also generates an Update event.See below.)"}
        SecGroupDelete {$eventName = "A group on the site collection is deleted."}
        SecGroupMemberAdd {$eventName = "A user is added to a group."}
        SecGroupMemberDelete {$eventName = "A user is removed from a group."}
        SecRoleBindBreakInherit {$eventName = "A subsite's inheritance of permission level definitions (that is, role definitions) is severed."}
        SecRoleBindInherit {$eventName = "A subsite is set to inherit permission level definitions (that is, role definitions) from its parent."}
        SecRoleBindUpdate {$eventName = "The permissions of a user or group for the audited object are changed."}
        SecRoleDefCreate {$eventName = "A new permission level (a combination of permissions that are given to people holding a particular role for the site collection) is created."}
        SecRoleDefDelete {$eventName = "A permission level (a combination of permissions that are given to people holding a particular role for the site collection) is deleted."}
        SecRoleDefModify {$eventName = "A permission level (a combination of permissions that are given to people holding a particular role for the site collection) is modified."}
        Update {$eventName = "An existing object is updated."}
        CheckOut {$eventName = " A document is checked Out."}
        View {$eventName = "Viewing of the object by a user."}
        ProfileChange {$eventName = "Change in a profile that is associated with the object."}
        SchemaChange {$eventName = "Change in the schema of the object."}
        Undelete {$eventName = "Restoration of an object from the Recycle Bin."}
        Workflow {$eventName = "Access of the object as part of a workflow."}
        FileFragmentWrite {$eventName = "A File Fragment has been written for the file."}
        Custom {$eventName = "Custom action or event."}
        default {$eventName = "The Event could not be determined."}
    }

    #Enter data in the row
    $row.SiteUrl = $site.Url
    $row.SiteID = $entry.SiteID
    $row.ItemName = $ItemName
    $row.ItemType = $entry.ItemType
    $row.UserID = $entry.UserID
    $row.UserName = $UserName
    $row.Occurred = $entry.Occurred
    $row.Event = $entry.Event
    $row.Description = $eventName
    $row.EventSource = $entry.EventSource
    $row.SourceName = $entry.SourceName
    $row.EventData = $entry.EventData
    $row.MachineName = $entry.MachineName
    $row.MachineIP = $entry.MachineIP

    #Add the row to the table
    $table.Rows.Add($row)

}

$date = get-date -format "d-M-yyyy"
$sDtae = [string]$date
$FileName = "AuditLogReport_For_" + $sDtae
#Export the CSV File to Folder Destination
$tabCsv = $table | export-csv C:\$FileName.csv -noType
```

Comment: Where does the archive get stored?

Comment: You can pass the location of the file where you want to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

To back up: It's part of the Content database, only supported solution is to backup the content database.

You can enable trimming to trim the audit log:

**Configure audit log trimming**

1. On the Site actions menu Site Actions Menu, click Site settings.
2. If you are not at the root of your site collection, under Site
   Collection Administration, click Go to top level site settings.

   NOTE    The Site Collection Administration section will not be
   available if you do not have the necessary permissions.
3. On the Site Settings page, under Site Collection Administration,
   click Site collection audit settings.
4. On the Configure Audit
   Settings page, in the Audit Log Trimming section, set Automatically
   trim the audit log for this site? to Yes. Optionally, specify the
   number of days of audit log data to retain.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx